# It seems `@GetMapping` doesn't work with `@Controller`, why is that?

Tags: spring-boot

Per the [doc](https://springframework.guru/spring-framework-annotations/), `@RestController` is just a convenience annotation which combines @Controller and @ResponseBody and `@GetMapping` is a composed annotation that acts as a shortcut for @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET), which means `@GetMapping` should work well with both `@RestController` and `@Controller`

In fact `@GetMapping` only works with `@RestController`.

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
  @GetMapping("/")
  public String hello(){
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

while

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
  @GetMapping("/")
  public String hello(){
    return "hello";
  }
}
```

doesn't work.

I know I can use `@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)` instead, I'd just like to know why. Could someone give a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@Controller
public class TestController {
    
     @GetMapping("/")
     @ResponseBody
    public String hello() {
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Add the @ResponceBody annotation then, it will work.

- The @Controller annotation indicates that the class is a “Controller”
  e.g. a web controller
- The @RestController annotation indicates
  that the class is a controller where @RequestMapping methods assume
  @ResponseBody semantics by default i.e. servicing REST API.